# Github Post-Receive Hook in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, github, amazon-ec2

I am trying to create a post-receive hook in Nodejs to update my server when my Github repo has been updated.

I have done this before in php. I am now using Nodejs and am unsure how it should be acheived.

I have looked at [this](http://cuppster.com/2011/05/12/diy-node-js-server-on-amazon-ec2/) blog post about setting up nodejs on an ec2 instance. It says:

```
Create a post-recieve hook that will copy over new code after it’s been pushed to the repository

$ cat > hooks/post-receive

#!/bin/sh
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/ubuntu/www
export GIT_WORK_TREE
git checkout -f

$ chmod +x hooks/post-receive
```

I am unsure what exactly the above code is doing and how it should be implemented.

Any ideas on the best way of doing this?

I am running a basic 32-bit Amazon Linux EC2 instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A git bare repository doesn't include the working tree. So to use the files you have to check them out.

putting the above script in (pseudo path) ec2:mybaregitrepo/hooks/post-recieve will cause it to run every time you push to ec2.

Which means:

```
#!/bin/sh
//set git working tree (the files you can use) to the path /home/ubuntu/www
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/ubuntu/www
export GIT_WORK_TREE
//force git checkout so that your files will be put into the working tree.
git checkout -f
```

than:

```
//make the post-recieve hook executable so that it can run when you push commits to ec2
chmod +x hooks/post-receive
```

here is a decent runthrough of setting up a remote bare git repo
http://toroid.org/ams/git-website-howto

Answer (score 0):

My `node` (`Express`) app runs under `forever`, so I use the following handler, which basically does a `git pull` and kills itself (therefore respawning).

```
function handleGitHub(req, res, next) {

  setTimeout(function() {
    var shouldRestart = !app.config.webhook || req.body.head_commit.message.indexOf(app.config.webhook) > -1;
    console.log('[GITHUB] WebHook Received for "%s" (WebHook: %s, Restart? %s)', req.body && req.body.head_commit.message, app.config.webhook && app.config.webhook, shouldRestart);
    if (!shouldRestart) {
      console.log('[GITHUB] Not restarting');
      return;
    }
    if (app.server_https && app.server_https.close) {
      console.log('[GITHUB] Closing HTTPS');
      app.server_https.close();
    }
    if (app.server && app.server.close) {
      console.log('[GITHUB] Closing HTTP');
      app.server.close();
    }
    setTimeout(function() {
      var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

      var shell = process.env.SHELL;
      var args = ['-c', 'git pull'];

      var path = require('path');
      var projectPath = '/path/to/your/project/folder'; //or path.join(__dirname, '....

      var opts = { cwd: projectPath };

      console.log('[GITHUB] Spawning...', opts);

      var spawnProcess = spawn(shell, args, opts);

      spawnProcess.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
        // could log these
      });

      spawnProcess.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
        // could log these
      });

      spawnProcess.on('close', function(exitCode) {
        console.log('[GITHUB] Spawn finished', exitCode);
        console.log('[GITHUB] Exiting...');
        console.log('-------------------------------------------------------');
        process.exit(0);
      });

    }, 1000);

  }, 500);
  res.send(200, 'OK');
}
```

Now, just use a route that points to this function:

```
app.post('/some_path_you_setup_in_github_web_hooks', handleGitHub);
```

You can setup your push hook in 
https://github.com/your_username/your_project/settings/hooks